# How to CATCH the error raised from Postgresql stored procedure in JAVA

Tags: java, postgresql

I have the below error code inside a SP. The SP is being created to save records in the postgresql DB. Before the record insert it checks if the combination is already present in the DB. Sorry I can not provide all SP code details but I would replicate the error scenario as below :

```
IF (var_RecordCount <> 0) THEN
    
    RAISE 'Error %, severity %, state % was raised. Message: %.', '50000', 5, 1, 'Selected combination is already present in Database...' USING ERRCODE = '50000';

ELSE
    --- DO Something Else
```

I am using java (Spring Boot) to call the SP as below :

```
    Connection conn = DatabaseConnection.connect();
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    
    Boolean isSuccess = false;
    
    try {
                
        stmt = conn.prepareStatement("call public.my-sp(?,?,?,?,?,?);");
        stmt.setInt(1, "");
        stmt.setString(2, "");
        stmt.setString(3, "");
        stmt.setString(4, "");
        stmt.setString(5, "");
        stmt.setString(6, "");
        
        int status = stmt.executeUpdate();
        isSuccess = (status == 0) || (status > 0);
        

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occurred during calling SP : my_sp().", e);
    } finally {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error in connection close.", e);
        }
    }


    return isSuccess;
```

My question is in Java how can I catch the error being raised from inside the SP. Are there any available methods to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`Statement.getWarnings()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#getWarnings--) like

```
isSuccess = (status == 0) || (status > 0);
if (!isSuccess) {
    SQLWarning swarn = stmt.getWarnings();
    while (swarn != null) {
        LOGGER.warn(swarn);
        swarn = swarn.getNextWarning();
    }
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks for ur valuable suggestion. Will implement and try out this and let u know the result.